# Is HTC one X AT&T and HTC one XL same?

Tags: htc-one-x, att, htc-one-xl

Just noticed HTC one X AT&T and HTC one XL has got same configuration. Are those mobile same ?

[HTC one X AT&T vs HTC one XL (GSM Arena)](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=4614&idPhone2=4572)

Actually, I read a article on which it was mentioned like " Android 4.2.1 ROM is cooked up for the HTC One XL (the AT&T One X) ". This tend to think me whether these two are same.

[Android 4.2.1 AOKP Custom ROM for the AT&T HTC One X](http://drippler.com/htc/one_x#!602019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **No, they are not the same.**
The long answer is as follows:

At least for dimensions, they are *not exactly* the same (HTC One XL, to the right, is a bit smaller)

[image: HTC One X AT&T] [image: HTC One XL]

Also, from the comparison table you talk about:

1. HTC One X AT&T wouldn't support HSDPA 900, while HTC One XL does.
2. HTC One X AT&T supports 4G network with LTE 700 MHz Class 17 / 1700 /
   2100, while HTC One XL does it with LTE 1800 / 2600.
3. HTC One X AT&T supports Mini-SIM, while HTC One XL supports Micro-SIM.
4. HTC One XL has Stereo FM radio with RDS, while HTC One X AT&T does not.
5. HTC One XL has 32 GB internal storage, HTC One X AT&T has 16 GB internal storage.

Sources:

- Left image: [HTC One AT&T at HTC US website](http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones/htc-one-x-att)
- Right image: [HTC One XL at HTC Australian website](http://www.htc.com/au/smartphones/htc-one-xl)

Comment: Actually, I read a article on which it was mentioned like " Android 4.2.1 ROM is cooked up for the HTC One XL (the AT&T One X) ". This tend to think me whether these two are same.

http://drippler.com/htc/one_x#!602019

Answer (score -2):

Nope, both have different features, and are not the same.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the differences?